# Unable to set transformations of animation to (0,0,0)

Tags: animation, unity

So my problem is that I have a character with three animation cycles (Idle, Walking, and Running). When animating, I accidentally placed the character to the right meaning my Location X isn't zero. Now because I want to import the character to Unity, I'm unable to use Delta Transform to correct my mistake. I know that I need to change the animation and set a correct transform on the x-axis for all keyframes but I don't know how. What should I do?[image: The Character needs to move 3.8942m to the left][image: Graph editor]

Comment: Set all X location to 0 in the Graph Editor.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I only have an imported fbx file. That means that for some reason I'm not able to change keyframes in the graph editor.

Comment: Try to zoom in the graph editor (hold ctrl+mmb and move the mouse up, or hit the numpad del). I can see the 5000 and the 10000 on the scale and it's not a good sign.

Comment: I zoomed into the graph editor but there are no visible keyframes. Is there a way I can maybe edit the keyframes in Unity?

Comment: This is wierd. Anyway there is an other method. Add an empty then add a child of contraint to the root bone (target is the empty). Correct the location with the empty, then bake the animation (search for "Bake Action"). Make sure check in the "Clear Constraints" option.

Comment: Thank you so much! This workaround is working perfectly even in Unity. For some reason I did not find this trick anywhere else but I recommend this to anyone stuck with a similar problem.